# Excel index match can't distinguish between upper and lower case letters

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using an Excel index & match formula on some data. The cells sometimes contain just individual letters as data. I've noticed that when using an index and match, the formula will match "a" with "A". How can I get my excel match formula to distinguish between letter cases?

Here is an example of what I have received.

[image]

Notice how I am trying to match on "a" only, however, it returns me the index of `some data`, which shows that it matches on "A".

How can I make sure my formula doesn't do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I get my excel match formula to distinguish between letter cases?

You need to use the [`EXACT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/exact-function-d3087698-fc15-4a15-9631-12575cf29926) function as well.

See [Check if a cell contains text (case-sensitive) - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/check-if-a-cell-contains-text-case-sensitive-7f302a1e-5a3b-421c-b00a-615c89bc39ba) and [INDEX and MATCH case-sensitive - Excel formula | Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formulas/index-and-match-case-sensitive) for more information

Comment: Excellent, thank you.